# Ajax.ActionLink with PartialView opens new page MVC4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive

I am building a ASP.NET MVC4(.5) web app.
I went trough much topics about the problem, tried every one of them but the problem didn't disappear.

I have a controller which returns a PartialView.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Subcategories(int id)
{
  IOrderedQueryable<Subcategory> subcategories = this.Data.Subcategories
                                                   .All()
                                                   .Where(sub => sub.Category.Id == id)
                                                   .OrderBy(cat => cat.Name);

  var request = this.Request.IsAjaxRequest();
  IEnumerable<ConciseSubcategoryViewModel> model = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ConciseSubcategoryViewModel>>(subcategories);
  return this.PartialView("_Subcategories", model);
}
```

I have this bundle, included in the bottom of my _Layout page.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/jquery").Include(
              "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"));
```

But, when I create Ajax.ActionLink in one of my views and call it, the variable "request" in the controller has value "false", the cause of the request is DOCUMENT instead of XHR and returns the partial view in new tab of the browser.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
  Model.Name,
  "Subcategories",
  "Items",
  new { Id = Model.Id },
  new AjaxOptions() {
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "subcategories-wrapper"
})
```

Thanks for the help.I just can't see anything wrong.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Do you have any js errors in your page ? Check your browser console

Comment: The problem is that it directly redirects me to the new tab, so the console refreshes and I can't see any errors...

Comment: enable "preserve log" and it will keep it between redirects. Also make sure your `~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` properly loaded to browser

Comment: Every script, used in the website is loaded successfully, I manually checked the response of the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file and it is ok

Comment: Then your code should work fine.

Comment: But it doesn't.It just opens in new tab...I tried restarting Visual Studio, rebuilding the solution, reinstalling unobtrusive..Nothing helped

Comment: i tried your code (MVC5 project) and it worked

Comment: Make sure you have unobtrusive js turned on in the web config. <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" /> in app settings.

Answer (score 0):

So guys I don't think the problem  is here but, see what happens when I return the view, which creates the ajax:

```
@model AddItemViewModelBag
@section styles {
  <link href="~/Stylesheets/add-item.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Ново изделие";
}


@Html.Partial("_AddItemForm", Model.AddItemBindingModel)

@Html.Partial("_Categories", Model.Categories)

@section scripts{
  <script src="~/Scripts/add-item.js"></script>
}
```

In the `_Categories` view:

```
@model IEnumerable<ConciseCategoryViewModel>

<div class="category-manager hidden-manager">  
  <div class="categories-container">
    <div class="heading">Изберете категория</div>
    <div id="categories-wrapper">
      @Html.DisplayForModel()
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcategories-container">
    <div id="subcategories-wrapper">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the ConciseCategoryViewModel

```
@model ConciseCategoryViewModel

<div class="category-option" data-category-id="@Model.Id">
  @Ajax.ActionLink(
    Model.Name,
    "Subcategories",
    "Items",
    new { Id = Model.Id },
    new AjaxOptions() {
       HttpMethod = "GET",
       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
       UpdateTargetId = "subcategories-wrapper"
    })
 </div>
```

I think that it can still use the unobtrusive, included in the _Layout page...